# Postfix 5.7.1 Relay access denied

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I know there's a lot of similar questions here but none has helped me.
So I have a Debian 7.0 server with postfix and dovecot working on it with a self-signed certificate. I can send emails to other servers using telnet when I'm connected to a server via SSH but I can't send emails via Thunderbird client with the following error message:

> An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:
>   5.7.1  : Relay access denied. Please check the message recipient   anton.kumaigorodskiy@outlok.com and try again.

First of all, my ISP blocks port 25 so I'm using port 465 like this:
[image]

Here's a part my master.cf that I've edited on setup:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy

submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth

smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

Here's my main.cf:

```
myhostname = mail.server.com
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.server.com, server.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/mailcert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/mail.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3

smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1

local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps

inet_protocols = all
```

Here's my dovecot.conf:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
passdb {
  args = %s
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"

service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}

ssl=required
ssl_cert =< /etc/ssl/certs/mailcert.pem
ssl_key =< /etc/ssl/private/mail.key
```

And finally the contents of my mail.log when the error is happening:

```
Nov 14 13:17:24 Test postfix/smtpd[10720]: connect from 49-3-134-95.pool.ukrtel.net[95.134.3.49]
Nov 14 13:17:25 Test postfix/smtpd[10720]: Anonymous TLS connection established from 49-3-134-95.pool.ukrtel.net[95.134.3.49]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Nov 14 13:17:25 Test postfix/smtpd[10720]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 49-3-134-95.pool.ukrtel.net[95.134.3.49]: 554 5.7.1 <anton.kumaigorodskiy@outlok.com>: Relay access denied; from=<anton@server.com> to=<anton.kumaigorodskiy@outlok.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.0.101]>
Nov 14 13:17:30 Test postfix/smtpd[10720]: disconnect from 49-3-134-95.pool.ukrtel.net[95.134.3.49]
```

What should I do to fix this issue?

**================ UPDATE ====================**

After reading http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html and http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL here are the changes I made:

New master.cf:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
      -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
      -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
      -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
      -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname

    smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

Added to main.cf:

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

Added to dovecot.conf:

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
```

Still no luck, I'm getting exactly the same error when I try to send a letter.

Comment: Have you restarted postfix and dovecot?

Comment: @NickW sure, I've restarted them both after making changes to conf files. Both restarted without error messages.

Comment: Ok, add in these two lines to your master.cf `-o smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
 -o   smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous`

Comment: Or main.cf, without the `-o`

Comment: Tried connecting on port 587, you have a submission service configured in your master.cf for that purpose. What does the mail.log say about the failed SASL-Login? I can't see any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not authenticating via SASL.

You have this set on submission:

`-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject`

The first allows mynetworks (which seems to be only localhost), the second allows ony authenticated users. Your log shows you establishing an anonymous TLS connection, but no SASL auth.

I don't see any SASL configuration in your main.cf, you may want to have a look at [this](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html).

Comment: Thanks, I've read the articles and made some changes but sadly nothing has changed. I've updated my post with what I've done.

Comment: OK, I've just installed everything from the scratch following this tutorial: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-setup-simple-but-yet-powerful-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-and-sasl-in-debian-6-squeeze/ and it works. Thanks anyway for pointing to the issue.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes tossing it all and starting again fresh is the best option :)

Answer (score 2):

As NickW said, your configuration only allow you to send mail anonymously from host in *mynetworks* and authenticated from other locations.

So you have two solutions :

- enabling SASL authentication
- adding your public IP to Postfix *mynetworks* parameter to allow you sending mail without being authenticated (I don't recommend this solution if you send mails from many locations)

Comment: I'm trying to enable SASL auth with no success so far. Please take a look at my updated post, perhaps you could spot some error there.